# How do I show that f is surjective iff $N = f(f^{−1}(N))$ for all $N \subset B$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B$ be non-empty sets and $f : A \to B$ a mapping. Show that $f$ is surjective if and only if $N = f\left(f^{−1}(N)\right)$ for all $N ⊂ B$.

I don't know where to start. I got some answers but I still don't how to continue. I'm frustrated and only got this:

[image: my attempt]

Comment: The community would be able to help you better if you use mathjax

Comment: And use complete sentences in your attempted proof. What is the argument that your symbolic expressions are helping to convey?

Comment: First note that for any function $f:A\to B$ and any $N\subset A$, we have (why?) $f(f^{-1}(N))\subset N$. Now if $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$, then $f$ must be surjective (why?). Finally, if $f$ is surjective and $N\subset B$, then for any $n\in N$, there exists a $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=n$. But then $a\in f^{-1}(N)$ so $n=f(a)\in f(f^{-1}(N))$. This is true $\forall n\in N$ so $N\subset f(f^{-1}(N))$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\to B$ be a function.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $f$ a surjective function and $N\subset B$. We suppose a $b\in N$; by surjectivity of $f$ there exists an $a\in A$ such that $b=f(a)$. Thus $a\in f^{-1}(N)$ and $b\in f(f^{-1}(N))$, so $N\subset f(f^{-1}(N))$ (1). For the converse inclusion let us suppose a $b\in f(f^{-1}(N))$; then by definition there exists an $a\in f^{-1}(N)$ such that $b=f(a)$, so $b\in N$ (2). From (1),(2) $N=f(f^{-1}(N))$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $N=f(f^{-1}(N))$ for every $N\subset B$. Suppose $b\in B$; we apply the hypothesis for $N:=\{b\}\subset B$, which means that $\{b\}=f(f^{-1}(\{b\}))$, and we get that $b\in f(f^{-1}(\{b\}))$, so there exists an $a\in f^{-1}(\{b\})\subset A$, such that $b=f(a)$. This yields that $f$ is surjective.